# How to test endorsement policy for the business network in multiple organizations

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/stable/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html) tutorial to setup multiple organizations. According to step 13 before committing transaction requires both organizations should sign off. How can I test that both organizations are endorsing transaction?

Comment: Where would you like to test it? As a client, it's responsible to send endorsing transaction to peers of both organization and then collect signatures. Once peer get a block with transaction it executes VSCC which ensures that endorsement policy satisfied, e.g. transaction has enough valid signatures according to policy. Could you expand where would you like to make this check?

Comment: @ArtemBarger I want to check using API or someother way that transaction is signed by organization

Answer (score 1):

Give the proposal responses you are receiving from endorsing peer you can iterate to check validity of the signatures. Here for example code from Java SDK which handles this:

```
/*
 * Verifies that a Proposal response is properly signed. The payload is the
 * concatenation of the response payload byte string and the endorsement The
 * certificate (public key) is gotten from the Endorsement.Endorser.IdBytes
 * field
 *
 * @param crypto the CryptoPrimitives instance to be used for signing and
 * verification
 *
 * @return true/false depending on result of signature verification
 */
public boolean verify(CryptoSuite crypto) {

    if (isVerified()) { // check if this proposalResponse was already verified   by client code
        return isVerified();
    }

    if (isInvalid()) {
        this.isVerified = false;
    }

    FabricProposalResponse.Endorsement endorsement = this.proposalResponse.getEndorsement();
    ByteString sig = endorsement.getSignature();

    try {
        Identities.SerializedIdentity endorser = Identities.SerializedIdentity
                .parseFrom(endorsement.getEndorser());
        ByteString plainText = proposalResponse.getPayload().concat(endorsement.getEndorser());

        if (config.extraLogLevel(10)) {

            if (null != diagnosticFileDumper) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10000);
                sb.append("payload TransactionBuilderbytes in hex: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(proposalResponse.getPayload().toByteArray()));
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("endorser bytes in hex: "
                        + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(endorsement.getEndorser().toByteArray()));
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("plainText bytes in hex: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(plainText.toByteArray()));

                logger.trace("payload TransactionBuilderbytes:  " +
                        diagnosticFileDumper.createDiagnosticFile(sb.toString()));
            }

        }

        this.isVerified = crypto.verify(endorser.getIdBytes().toByteArray(), config.getSignatureAlgorithm(),
                sig.toByteArray(), plainText.toByteArray()
        );
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException | CryptoException e) {
        logger.error("verify: Cannot retrieve peer identity from ProposalResponse. Error is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        this.isVerified = false;
    }

    return this.isVerified;
} // verify
```

Of course you can achive same results with other SDK in pretty similar way.

Comment: Does this mode of endorsement in Fabric leaves it just to the client to implement the endorsement correctly? My question is, during the vscc validation at the peers, while you validate the transaction received from the orderer, do you validate the R/W sets and Signatures both ? [ Otherwise, i could dupe Fabric by just bypassing  the verification check and by sending the R/W set which might be just different in each response(from each peer). Rite?]

Comment: Yes, there is an MVCC validation as well as VSCC, one checks keys versions for concurrent modifications and second one ensures whenever transaction conforms endorsement policy.